# Google Cloud Engine - How to receive an email and handle in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine

I am using GCP to host a small Flask app and need to receive emails and process them.  Having read the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api) I have copied the sample code to test.

When I deploy I get the following error:

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/_ah/mail/.+' must be set
>   to 'auto' for runtime python37.

```
runtime: python37
inbound_services:
- mail
handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: handle_incoming_email.py
  login: admin
```

If I do as the instructions suggest I'm confused because:

1. How can GCP know how to handle the request.. I assume it can't which is why..
2. I also get the following error when I change the script to auto

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: login for handler '/_ah/mail/.+' is not allowed in
>   runtime python37.

Does GCP not support incoming email with Python 3.7 or is there a working around to have 3.7 on my Flask app and 2.7 on my mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Support here!

GCP does not support email handling with a Google App Engine application running in python 3.7, as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/), there's only documentation for python 2 which is the only one available.

The error you are getting in your app.yaml is due to that, and more specifically, the [script field for the hanlder](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_script) does not accept any other value than `auto`. Quoting the documentation:

> **Script:**
>
> Optional. Specifies that requests to the specific handler should target your app. The only accepted value for the script element is **auto**.

When you change your script value to `auto`, you are getting the INVALID_ARGUMENT error for your handler because of the incompatibility of the mail API with your python version.

Therefore in order to use the mail API, you can use third-party services as specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/sending-messages). There are three recommended services:

- [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/)
- [Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/integration/google/?p=google)
- [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/)